# Expo push notifications tool doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm trying to send a basic push notification to my android device through expo but I can not receive the notification, I tried https://expo.dev/notifications to see whats going wrong but I couldn't figure out because everything seems correct? I installed all the depencies: expo-notifications expo-device expo-constants

I have a token, and when I tried the token to send https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send with postman I get 200 as follow but no notification on my physical device:

```
{
    "data": {
        "status": "ok",
        "id": "idnumberhere"
    }
}
```

My code:

```
if (token !== null) {
const message = {
  to: token,
  sound: "default",
  title: title,
  body: body,
};

await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(message),
  categoryIdentifier: category ?? "",
});
```